# textbox dynamically change height when the user goes to a new line

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, height

In a WPF application I have a textbox. I have set `AcceptReturn` to `true`
But I need to make the textbox bigger when the user clicks enter. What I mean is currently when the user clicks on the enter key, the cursor goes to a new line however the text box is still the same height and the above line is now hidden. Can I make the textboxHeight change dynamically depending on it's content?

Thanks

PS: I cannot use textarea I need to stay with the textboxes

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to keep it a current size and use the vertical scrollbar.  But, if you're doing something that really requires it, place your TextBox into a Grid.  Set the Grid row height to auto.  Set the Height of the TextBox to Auto.  Set the VerticalAlignment of the textbox to Stretch.  In the code below I left the scrollbar settings in. You can change those how you see fit.

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="scriptTextBox" Margin="10" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Consolas, Courier New" 
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 MaxLines="9999" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=Script, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 />
     </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to use Textboxes.  Can you at least use an overriden Textbox?  This worked pretty well in my testing:

```
public class AutoHeightTextbox : TextBox {

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds) {
        Size unboundSize = new Size(this.Width, double.PositiveInfinity);
        Size textSize = base.MeasureOverride(unboundSize);
        this.Height = textSize.Height;
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }

}
```